# Getting the value of an attribute in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, attributes

How would one get the value of attribute1 (blah) in the following xml using xslt:

```
<name attribute1="blah" attribute2="blahblah">
</name>
```

Answer (score 307, accepted):

This is more of an xpath question, but like this, assuming the context is the parent element:

```
<xsl:value-of select="name/@attribute1" />
```

Comment: What if the context is not in the parent element?

Comment: again, this would be an xpath question ;

Comment: @Arty - I think what you're looking for is simply xsl:value-of select="./@attributename"

Comment: Can't it be simply `@attribute1`?